# how to check a unorder list for duplicates before adding a clone to that same list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

First, I clone the following div list:

```
<div class=".a_list"><p><input type="checkbox" />Testing A list</p></div>
<div class=".a_list"><p><input type="checkbox" />Testing A list</p></div>
<div class=".a_list"><p><input type="checkbox" />Testing A list</p></div>
```

```
$(".a_list").each(function(){
    $(this).clone().appendTo("#list").wrap("<li />");
});
```

How do I check the #list before adding the clone to the list

Comment: syntax error, corrected but the question remains the same. thanks for pointing out this syntax error

Comment: You should remove `.` from class names.

Comment: `How do I check the #list before adding the clone to the list` can you please explain this sentence? and @undefined eagle eyes! +1

Comment: Trying to clone the items from the .a_list and add it to the #list list but before adding to the #list check is there are duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first remove `.` from class names. You can use `filter` and `text` methods.

```
var $list = $('#list');
$(".a_list").each(function(){
    var $that = $(this); // Sorry, note that there was a typo here
    var e = $list.find('li').filter(function(){
         return $(this).text() === $that.text();
    }).length === 0;
    if (e) {
       $that.clone().wrap("<li/>").appendTo($list);
    }
});
```

Comment: on line #3 of your code, $this should be $(this), right?

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene Yes, I meant to say that, it was `$this` that should be `$(this)`.